# Getting name of location selected in Google Maps app

Tags: android, google-maps

I have developed an app that uses an intent and opens the google maps app. I need to get the name of the location that has been searched on the map. Is there any way to do this?
Plus, I dont want to use Google Maps or Places API.

Comment: only name of the location or you want to show that location in map ?

Comment: the google map application opens up. when the user searches for a location and it shows on the map,I need the name of that searched location